# Get ID of an Object After adding it to Database using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am beginner to Entity Framework.

Let's say I have a Person Entity and I need to add a new Person to Database.

My Database has a Person Table with Id, Name, Age, and email. where id is the PK.

To add a new Person. My code will look:

```
DatabaseEntities context = new DatabaseEntities();
Person p = new Person("name", age, "email");
context.AddToPersons(p);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**My Question is**: After adding the new person, How can I get the id of that person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id should automatically be set by the context.